# Override function from base class with a different enum

Tags: c#, enums, derived-class

Okay, the title may sound a bit confusing, just read my explanation here to understand what I mean:

I got a base class, lets call it `BaseProvider`. This class looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseProvider
{
    public abstract void NewItem(int type);
}
```

Now I add a second class that derives from the `BaseProvider`. Lets call it `TestProvider`:

```
public class TestProvider : BaseProvider
{
    public override void NewItem(int type)
    {

    }
}
```

**Okay, now here comes my question / problem:**

As there are different sub-types that this provider should be able to handle, I created the parameter `int type`. However it would be much nicer to be able to use Enums. And as every data provider will have a different set of sub-types I can't reuse a already existing one. 
Now my method signature has to match exactly the one from the base class which makes it impossible to change the parameter type to an enum (even though an enum is basically an int).

I did try to define my deriving class like the following:

```
public class TestProvider : BaseProvider
{
    public override void NewItem(MyEnum type)
    {

    }
}

enum MyEnum : int
{
    TEST = 1
}
```

As excpeted this does not work...
So my question now is:

**Is it possible to overwrite a base function with a different parameter type that derives from the parameter type defined in the base class? If yes how?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, absolutely not - and here's why... This code still has to work:

```
BaseProvider provider = new TestProvider();
provider.NewItem(10);
```

That's just the normal requirements of polymorphism. You can't change a signature when you're overriding, because callers may be considering your instance in terms of the base class instead. (Indeed, if they're *not* doing so, why bother having the abstract method at all?)

Now you can *overload* the method:

```
public override void NewItem(int type)
{
    NewItem((MyEnum) type);
}

public void NewItem(MyEnum type)
{
    ...
}
```

That's not quite the same thing, but it probably achieves what you want.

Alternatively, you could make `BaseProvider` generic:

```
public abstract class BaseProvider<T>
{
    public abstract void NewItem(T type);
}

public class TestProvider : BaseProvider<MyEnum>
{
    public override void NewItem(MyEnum type)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually makes sense, however someone told me that this should be possible and that they did it somewhere in their code. Was not sure though :)

Comment: @RononDex: Well, you'd need to talk to them about what they *actually* did... but as you've written it, that just wouldn't compile.

Comment: Actually if you think about it, it should be theoretically possible. The .NET runtime should be able to parse your int that you pass to the function through TestProvider.NewItem into the corresponding enum value, as the enum is basically just an integer.

Comment: @RononDex: No, the language prohibits it. The language *could* have been designed to allow that sort of thing, but instead it was designed to keep enums separate to `int` in general. That keeps it more typesafe, apart from anything else. So given the actual language design, the person you were talking to is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually missing out the concept of overriding here. It is not about changing method definition. It is about changing method behavior. What you could do here is either overload, or make sure you cast your `enum` as `int` before call.